# Write ggplot2 layers on different lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

This might by a silly question but I'm adding quite a few layers on a ggplot2 and this makes finally a huge line on screen, quite difficult to read.

Say I want to write:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x,y))
     + geom_point()
     + geom_contour(data = another_df, aes(z=z))
     + etc.
```

Instead of having:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_contour(data = another_df, aes(z=z)) + etc.
```

for an easy reading of the code. This returns an error in R because it's not all in the same line. How could I do that ? I have tried to add a `c( ... )` but it creates a list an not a plot.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave the `+` at the end of the previous line, not the start of the next:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x,y)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_contour(data = another_df, aes(z=z)) +
     ....
```

R won't let you do:

```
1
+ 2
```

*and* get the answer you were looking for. It's exactly the same with your example except an error is thrown because the method for `+` is expecting 2 arguments and is only getting one.

Comment: ok this WAS a silly question indeed, especially looking at your second example !